Is it safe to delete ~/.cache/vscode-cpptools in vscode?
I use VS Code to SSH to university server. I've already set the IntelliSenseCache Path to another path. However, this only moves the ipch file to that path, while other files in ~/.cache/vscode-cpptools are still there, which costs about 2.2G space.

The university quota for each student home directory is 2G. So is it safe to delete ~/.cache/vscode-cpptools without influencing VS Code functionalities? Does this directory have extensions or something important?
(I searched but most answers are about deleting/moving the ipch folder, which I already have done)

If you just rename the folder (for backup purposes) does VS Code still work?

It's just caches, so it's fine. I just did it and nothing bad happened.
But the next time you open a workspace with C++ files where the cpptools extension is enabled, the caches for that workspace will just get generated again.
You can disable one of those types of files (ipch) by putting "C_Cpp.intelliSenseCacheSize": 0, in settings.json.
As far as I know, at the time of this writing, there is no way to disable the .browse.vc.db files. There are a number of issue tickets regarding the space consumption and disk writes for those files.

Fix browse database goes big unexpectedly (#9837)
#9881
Closed
"browse.VC.DB" causing me problems, constantly writes to disk (Unreal Engine project)
#7849
Huge .browse.VC.db file
#150
Limit size of .browse.VC.db to avoid filling up disk
#3470

